# Angular2-Not passing data to modal dialog

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/L6cSKd

For some reason, I can't understand how to pass data to my modal dialog. Also, after looking at the Plunker, if you think there is an easier way to do the modals, please let me know.

Man, this Angular2 stuff is difficult to debug on Plunker, too. Any tips on how to debug it?

If I put a breakpoint on the show function for `PrimaryModalComponent`, I can see that the `count`
is getting passed and `this.count` is also being set. I just can't figure out why it is not getting set when my dialog shows. Could it be that the `#primary-modal` is in `alert.detail`?

**alert.detail.html**

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let alert of alerts">
    <div style="padding-left: 25px;" class="alert_links col-sm-12">
        <i class="fa fa-warning fa-red"></i>&nbsp;
        <a href="#" *ngIf="alert.alert_type=='critical'" (click)="criticalmodal.show(alert.count)"
           title="There are {{ alert.count }} {{alert.alert_type}} alerts, click to view details">{{ alert.count }} {{alert.alert_type}} alerts
        </a>
        <a href="#" *ngIf="alert.alert_type=='other'" (click)="criticalmodal.show(alert.count)"
           title="There are {{ alert.count }} {{alert.alert_type}} alerts, click to view details">{{ alert.count }} {{alert.alert_type}} alerts
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
<critical-modal #criticalmodal>
    <div class="app-modal-header">
        There are {{this.count}} Critical Alerts
    </div>
    <div class="app-modal-body">
        Showing Critical Alerts Here!
    </div>
    <div class="app-modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="criticalmodal.hide()">Close</button>
    </div>
</critical-modal>
<primary-modal #primarymodal>
    <div class="app-modal-header">
        There are {{this.count}} Other Alerts
    </div>
    <div class="app-modal-body">
        Showing Other Alerts Here!
    </div>
    <div class="app-modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="primarymodal.hide()">Close</button>
    </div>
</primary-modal>
```

**alert-detail.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { CriticalModalComponent } from './critical-modal';
import { PimarylModalComponent } from './primary-modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'alert-detail',
  templateUrl: './src/alert.detail.html'
})

export class AlertDetail {
    constructor() {
        this.alerts =
        [
            {
             "alert_type":"critical",
             "count": 3
            },
            {
             "alert_type":"other",
             "count":18
            }
        ];        
    };
    };
}
```

**primary-modal.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'primary-modal',
  template: `
  <div (click)="onContainerClicked($event)" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" [ngClass]="{'in': visibleAnimate}"
       [ngStyle]="{'display': visible ? 'block' : 'none', 'opacity': visibleAnimate ? 1 : 0}">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header modal-primary">
          <ng-content select=".app-modal-header"></ng-content>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <ng-content select=".app-modal-body"></ng-content>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <ng-content select=".app-modal-footer"></ng-content>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .modal {
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    }
  `]
})
export class PrimaryModalComponent {

  public visible = false;
  private visibleAnimate = false;

  constructor(){}

  public show(count): void {
    this.visible = true;
    this.count = count;
    setTimeout(() => this.visibleAnimate = true, 100);
  }

  public hide(): void {
    this.visibleAnimate = false;
    setTimeout(() => this.visible = false, 300);
  }

  public onContainerClicked(event: MouseEvent): void {
    if ((<HTMLElement>event.target).classList.contains('modal')) {
      this.hide();
    }
  }
}
```

**critical-modal.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'critical-modal',
  template: `
  <div (click)="onContainerClicked($event)" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" [ngClass]="{'in': visibleAnimate}"
       [ngStyle]="{'display': visible ? 'block' : 'none', 'opacity': visibleAnimate ? 1 : 0}">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header modal-critical">
          <ng-content select=".app-modal-header"></ng-content>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <ng-content select=".app-modal-body"></ng-content>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <ng-content select=".app-modal-footer"></ng-content>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .modal {
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    }
  `]
})
export class CriticalModalComponent {

  public visible = false;
  private visibleAnimate = false;
  public count = 0;

  constructor(){}

  public show(count): void {
    this.visible = true;
    this.count = count;
    setTimeout(() => this.visibleAnimate = true, 100);
  }

  public hide(): void {
    this.visibleAnimate = false;
    setTimeout(() => this.visible = false, 300);
  }

  public onContainerClicked(event: MouseEvent): void {
    if ((<HTMLElement>event.target).classList.contains('modal')) {
      this.hide();
    }
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BootstrapModalModule, BuiltInOptions } from 'ngx-bootstrap-modal';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AlertDetail } from './alert.detail.component';
import { CriticalModalComponent } from './critical-modal';
import { PimarylModalComponent } from './primary-modal';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AlertDetail,
        CriticalModalComponent,
        PrimaryModalComponent
    ],
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent,
        AlertDetail
    ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are not passing data to child component

In **alert.detail.html**

```
<primary-modal #primarymodal [count]="count">
    <div class="app-modal-header">
        There are {{this.count}} Other Alerts
    </div>
</primary-modal>
```

---

```
   <a *ngIf="alert.alert_type=='other'" href="#" (click)="count = alert.count; primarymodal.show(alert.count)"
       title="There are {{ alert.count }} {{alert.alert_type}} alerts, click to view details">
       {{ alert.count }} {{alert.alert_type}} alerts
    </a>
```

**In alert.detail.component.ts**
Declare the variable  `public count;`

**In primary-modal.ts**

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
export class PrimaryModalComponent {
  @Input() count;
```

**plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/YfY7AA95Y3wTWhIJpFOs?p=preview -->  other alerts
Hope it helps!!